# CSS state for current menu page?

Tags: html, css

To begin with, I have an unordered list that holds my menu.

```
<ul id='css3menu1' class='topmenu'>
    <li class='topmenu'>
        <a href='home.html'>Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class='topmenu'>
        <a href='forum.php'>Forum</a>
    </li>
    <li class='topmenu'>
        <a href='policy.html'>Policy</a>
    </li>
    <li class='topmenu'>
        <a href='logout.php'>Log out</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

What I want to do is whenever the user is on a page, the hover state to become active. In other words, change the background color of the menu item with a darker one depending on which page the user is.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're interested in jQuery solution

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $('#css3menu1 li a[href="'+location.href.split('/').pop()+'"]').addClass('active');
  });
</script>
```

---

```
.active {
  background: #f1f1f1;
  border-top: 3px solid #cecece;
}
```

***Note:** Put script just before the `</body>` tag and of course include jQuery library in the head section of your document.

Comment: this + `!important` did the trick. Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

The most common way to accomplish this is to add a class, like `active`, to the link of the current page. Exactly how to do it depends on your templating engine.

Then you add that rule in your css :)

Comment: Yes, but how do I select that state so I can style it? Because I thought `active` was for already visited links. Furthermore, how would I know which page the user is on?

Comment: `:active` is a pseudo class. You can freely create an `.active` class.

Comment: Class names don't mean anything really, you give them meaning, so you add a rule `.active { background: gray; }` so any element with that class gets the background (most likely the same style you're using for `:hover`).

Comment: If I do that for each `<li>` element, how could I know which page is the current one selected?

Comment: How to know which page the user is on? Well how are you generating the html? It depends on your stack and templating engine, usually you have ways to add conditionals and do something like `<% if Url == "home.html">active<% endif>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var url = window.location.href;

$('.topmenu a').filter(function() {
    return this.href == url;
}).addClass('active');
```

this should work.
And adding a css-class for "active"

```
.topmenu.active {
    background-color: black;
}
```

**EDIT / UPDATE**
added jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2XeWB/

this.href doesn't take the relative path. It returned the fullpath whatever the href is set. So it compares the exact location.href with the href of that url-element.

It is a very short and simple solution :)

Comment: Doesn't add the class.

Comment: Use
    `function getCurentFileName(){
    var pagePathName= window.location.pathname;
    return pagePathName.substring(pagePathName.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
}`

to get the current filename

Comment: this.href -> doesn't return a relative path. So you cannot test it on jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

How to Add Active Class to a Navigation Menu Based on URL

**HTML**

```
 <menu id="nav">

    <ul>
        <li><a href="active.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="active1.html">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="active2.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="active3.html">Portfolio</a></li>
    </ul>

</menu>
```

**CSS**

```
    #nav {
    margin:200px auto;
    width:430px;
    }

#nav ul {
    list-style:none;
    background-color:#64abfb;
    }

#nav ul li {
    display:inline-block;
    line-height:44px;
    }

#nav ul li a {
    margin:10px;
    color:#FFF;
    padding:4px;
    font-size:20px;
    text-decoration:none;
    }

#nav ul li a:hover {
    border-bottom:3px #FFF solid;
    }

#nav ul li .active {
    border-bottom:3px #FFF solid;
    }
```

**JavaScript**

```
  $(function() {
     var pgurl = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
     $("#nav ul li a").each(function(){
          if($(this).attr("href") == pgurl || $(this).attr("href") == '' )
           $(this).addClass("active");
     })});
```

The example above is from [this](http://andornagy.com/active-class-navigation-menu/) link. Visit it for more information and examples.

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript:

```
$(function () {
    var url = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
    $('[href$="' + url + '"]').parents("li").addClass("current_menu_item");
});
```

and in your css define current_menu_item:

```
#menu
{
    background: #292929;
}

#menu ul .current_menu_item > a /* highlight current menu, target immediate child */
{
    color: Yellow;
}

#menu ul li
{
    // menu list style
}

#menu ul li a
{
    // menu word style
}
```

Your html should look something like this:

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li>
           <a href='home.html'>Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class='topmenu'>
            <a href='forum.php'>Forum</a>
        </li>
        <li class='topmenu'>
            <a href='policy.html'>Policy</a>
        </li>
        <li class='topmenu'>
            <a href='logout.php'>Log out</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and lastly define where your javascript is in your page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/common.js"></script>
```